# How to update aws IAM permission to allow update bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a aws s3 bucket where I would like to store my images. I created an express API route which gets the presigned url. Through my Vue app I am posting an image to the s3 bucket using the presigned url. The image gets uploaded to the bucket fine.

I now want to view the image in the s3 bucket through the generated url, but I get AccessDenied in XML format. To resolve this issue I need to update the bucket policy, which I am unable to do since when i try i get:

```
You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy
After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:PutBucketPolicy action, choose Save changes.
Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3
```

I am fairly new to aws, how can i update my current policy to add **s3:PutBucketPolicy**. I can't find the option to add that policy.

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-and-attach-iam-policy.html

Comment: What changes do you think you need to make to the S3 bucket policy?

Comment: @jellycsc I have already created a IAM S3 policy which allows all S3 actions, does this not include s3:PutBucketPolicy?

Comment: @jarmod Currently the bucket policy is empty resulting in no access to bucket content, I need to add a policy to make the images publicly available.

Comment: @jellycsc I have just updated **s3:PutBucketPolicy** inside the JSON policy object, in the actions array. But I still get error that i don't have permission to update bucket policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, also my root user was not able to edit the policy. What worked for me was (i) changing the bucket accessibility from private to public, (ii) then I was able to change "edit" the policy of the s3 bucket as a root user (did not try as an IAM though), (iii) turned the bucket back to private.

There is this guide I found, which did not help - but it might be useful for other future issues:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/

Comment: Hats off to the "toggle private to public, make updates, then toggle back" tip! How this is considered a "security implementation" is beyond me. But I observe other AWS complications too, seemingly related to the subordinate nature of my shared SSO login.

Comment: I had the same issue. AWS has some serious policy creation issues. Luckily your workaround suggestion worked.

Comment: Your workaround helped me to create a bucket policy. It is strange that an IAM user or even the root user who created the bucket is not able to create the bucket polity.